# Errors in installing mpc

Tags: python, pip, mpc, meshroom

hi everyone when am trying to install mpc, by running the command:

```
pip install mpc
```

I get the following error:

```
  Using cached mpc-0.0.4.tar.gz (17 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [3 lines of output]
      error in mpc setup command: 'install_requires' must be a string or list of strings containing valid project/version requirement specifiers; Expected end or semicolon (after version specifier)
          numpy>=1<2
               ~~~^
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/locuslab/mpc.pytorch/issues/43 .

This has been [fixed in the repository](https://github.com/locuslab/mpc.pytorch/commit/63732fa85ab2a151045493c4e67653210ca3d7ff) but they haven't released a new version.

For the time being, you can install from Git:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/locuslab/mpc.pytorch
```